# Safari extension opening websocket

Tags: javascript, safari, websocket

I have a problem with opening a websocket connection with Safari 5.1.7 (Windows). Code I use works perfectly for Chrome extension. Error I get is `Unexpected response code: 500`.

I've read, that safari 5.x implements only older version of websocket protocol.

Is there anything I can do, to make it work? (Server is not in my control)

How are newer version on safari implementing websocket protocol?

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: The problem was in old version of safari, which implements old version of websocket protocol (server side in my case used implemented newer version)