# Safari on Windows 8 won't connect using websocket

Tags: javascript, sockets, ssl, safari

I am trying to connect a serer to a HTML app using Safari but they do connect. 
I am running Windows 8.1 with Safari 5.1.7.

No error is being appearing in the Safari developer's tool's console. It simply doesn't connect with an undefined close code. I think maybe that Windows 8.1 and higher simply don't support Websockets for Safari since Apple discontinued Windows support for Safari.

I am trying to connect using the loopback address, so I have tried:

`ws://127.0.0.1:9002`

as well as:

`ws://127.0.0.1:9002/websocket`

to no avail. Does anyone have a good reason why this isn't working?

Comment: websockets are tcp sockets like any other. there's nothing special about them, other than being creatable via JS inside a browser. unless Apple was using some MS-provided library to add websockets to safari, which isn't available in Win8 anymore, there's no reason safari should care what version of windows it's running under.

Comment: @MarcB I figured that. but maybe they did use a specific MS library. I know that Safari 5.1.7 was the last available Safari supported for Windows and that was Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Using previous questions [Connecting to IIS 8 from Safari 5.1.7 by WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628211/connecting-to-iis-8-from-safari-5-1-7-by-websocket) and [Safari extension opening websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193200/safari-extension-opening-websocket):

Safari 5.1.7 uses an out-dated websocket standard [hybi](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol) while most recent applications needing websocket capabilities use [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). This incompatibility is the issue.

I don't know, however, whether the incompatibility is coming from the Server running in the background or Windows 8.1. Maybe someone can build on my answer.